# how to render to response?

Tags: python, django

I am sending list to a template using render_to_response. I am using django shortcuts. Hoe to do that? How to set context instance with a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def my_view(request):
    mylist = ['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3']

    return render_to_response('template.html', {'mylist':mylist})
```

You can then access and enumerate `list` in the template like this (amongst other methods):

```
{% for i in mylist %}
   {{ i }}, 
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Like any template value.

```
def some_view(request):
    # ...
    my_data_dictionary = { 'somelist': my_list }
    return render_to_response('my_template.html',
                              my_data_dictionary,
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

By the way, there's a [nice documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/).

Answer (score 0):

You can send a list in a context. For instance:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
context = dict(my_list = my_list)
render_to_response(template, context)
```

Read the relevant [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.render_to_response) for more information.

If you want [additional information](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#optional-arguments) to be passed to the template then use a `RequestContext` to wrap the context dictionary. You will need to enable the appropriate context processor for this.