# Other templates are not inheriting FOR LOOP in my base template

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-templates, django-views

The loop is actually for the Navigation. Listing Categories and Shops who sells or render services under each category. 
Please.. I'm new to Django and Python. And i'm sorry if i'm very slow to getting this things... Thanks

models.py

```
class ShopCategories(models.Model):
category = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
def __str__(self):
    return self.category

class NewShop(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(ShopCategories)
    main_image = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    tagline = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Enter tagline here2')
    description = models.TextField(default='enter shop description')
    shop_image = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
```

views.py

```
def homepage(request):
   return render_to_response('index.html')

def basefile(request):
    cat1 = NewShop.objects.filter(category_id=1)
    cat2 = NewShop.objects.filter(category_id=2)
    cat3 = NewShop.objects.filter(category_id=3)
    cat4 = NewShop.objects.filter(category_id=4)
    name1 = ShopCategories.objects.filter(id=1)
    name2 = ShopCategories.objects.filter(id=2)
    name3 = ShopCategories.objects.filter(id=3)
    name4 = ShopCategories.objects.filter(id=4)

    return  render_to_response('base.html', {'Shop_cat1':cat1, 'Shop_cat2':cat2, 'Shop_cat3':cat3,
                                        'Shop_cat4':cat4,'shop_name1':name1, 'shop_name2':name2,
                                        'shop_name3':name3, 'shop_name4':name4})
```

base.html

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="current-menu-item">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="current-menu-item">
           <a href="/">ENTOURAGE MALL</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown pi-mega-fw menu-item-has-children">
           <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" role="button">SHOPS</a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
           <div class="pi-mega-content">
              <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-md-3 pi-mm-col">
                    <ul class="pi-mm-list">
                    {% for shop in shop_name1 %}
                       <li>
                          <h3> {{ shop }}</h3>
                      </li>
                    {% endfor %}
                    {% for cat in Shop_cat1  %}
                       <li><a href="#">{{ cat }}</a></li>
                    {% endfor %}
                   </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 pi-mm-col">
                    <ul class="pi-mm-list">
                    {% for shop in shop_name2 %}
                       <li>
                          <h3> {{ shop }}</h3>
                      </li>
                    {% endfor %}
                    {% for cat in Shop_cat2  %}
                       <li><a href="#">{{ cat }}</a></li>
                    {% endfor %}
                   </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 pi-mm-col">
                    <ul class="pi-mm-list">
                    {% for shop in shop_name3 %}
                       <li>
                          <h3> {{ shop }}</h3>
                      </li>
                    {% endfor %}
                    {% for cat in Shop_cat3  %}
                       <li><a href="#">{{ cat }}</a></li>
                    {% endfor %}
                   </ul>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
       </li>
    </ul>
 </li>
 <li class="menu-item">
    <a href="contact" role="button">ENTOURAGE LOUNGE</a>
 </li>
 <li class="menu-item">
    <a href="contact" role="button">About MALL</a>
 </li>
 <li class="menu-item">
    <a href="contact" role="button">BLOG</a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

**index.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %} This is Homepage {% endblock title %}
```

Urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^$', views.homepage),
url(r'^base/', views.basefile)
]

if settings.DEBUG:

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root= settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, docuemt_root= settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

It works just fine in base.html. But when i {% extends base.html %} in index or other templates. The templates loads just fine, but the FOR loop isnt functional. What exactly am i doing wrong?

Comment: where you implement a context of `shop_name1` at the backend?

Comment: @SancaKembang i really do not understand what you mean.

Comment: for shop_name1 in shop_name1? interesting loop

Comment: @AlexanderTyapkov .. I'm just a beginner with django. I'm really just learning alot of new things. I just recently changed the variable names you mentioned above .. Thanks!!!... Please can you help me with the FOR Loop...

Comment: @DanielKilanko ok, just provide more code, for instance the view which is in use and also probably the full version of template

Comment: @AlexanderTyapkov ... I just updated my questions. Thank you

Comment: firstly you use loops to iterate over one variable. Here is example how you can provide lists to context http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635073/how-to-render-to-response

Comment: @DanielKilanko secondly you wrote that you don't have problem in base view but have it when you extend base.html. And there is no code for the part where you actually have problem

Comment: @AlexanderTyapkov I;m really sorry i'm not getting it right.. I'm very new to programming... I have added the index.html ....Thanks

Comment: @AlexanderTyapkov The FOR loop is inside the header. And its not inside any block. So, im wondering why the NAVIGATION links are showing fine when i browse localhost/base  but checking localhost/index i get all static files load fine and site render properly but not NAVIGATION

Comment: @DanielKilanko where do you have your navigation links? I don't see it in base template

Comment: @AlexanderTyapkov Please check again.. Just added more stuffs.. Thanks

Comment: Post also index view please.

Comment: @AlexanderTyapkov..... You mean the index.html .. Its posted.

Comment: I mean homepage view

Comment: @AlexanderTyapkov Updated

Comment: In homepage you should provide the same variables as in basefile. Just copy them from one view to another. It is really simple thing to do.

Comment: Thanks a lot... I thought of that, but i felt i was breaking the DRY. Thanks alot, just tested and its working for me :)

Comment: @DanielKilanko you are welcome!) just mark the question as answered then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should provide context in homepage view in the same way as in basefile view:

```
def homepage(request):
    cat1 = NewShop.objects.filter(category_id=1)
    cat2 = NewShop.objects.filter(category_id=2)
    cat3 = NewShop.objects.filter(category_id=3)
    cat4 = NewShop.objects.filter(category_id=4)
    name1 = ShopCategories.objects.filter(id=1)
    name2 = ShopCategories.objects.filter(id=2)
    name3 = ShopCategories.objects.filter(id=3)
    name4 = ShopCategories.objects.filter(id=4)

    return render_to_response('index.html', {'Shop_cat1':cat1, 'Shop_cat2':cat2, 'Shop_cat3':cat3,
                                        'Shop_cat4':cat4,'shop_name1':name1, 'shop_name2':name2,
                                        'shop_name3':name3, 'shop_name4':name4})
```